# scraping by python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I want to scrape data using python after clicking a show more button but the link or the url is not change, I used selenium but it does not work, I made this:
`folder = driver.find_element("xpath","//button[@id='gsc_bpf_more']").click()`
`url = driver.current_url`
`result = requests.get(url)`
then i got the content of the site, but it does not work, that just got the data before clicking the button as i did not click it
what should i do to get the data after click show more button (it does not change the url)

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element and your code trials.

Comment: Why used `request.get(url)`? This will return a new page which hasn't click show more btn out of selenium. You can use `result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath...')`.

Comment: @Shou ok then what should i do, i mean that just assign clicking button value to result which is noun i think, or if you can explain pls